# How to prove logical consequence in predicate calculus

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We say that $\psi$ is logical consequence of $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n$ if every models of $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n$ is a model of $\psi$ and, in this case, we write $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n \vDash \psi$.

Now: I know how to prove that $\psi$ is a logical consequence of $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n$ in propositional calculus. I have simply to use the truth tables. But what about predicate calculus? Can you show me an exemple in the case of predicate calculus? In predicate calculus, how do we prove that $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n \vDash \psi$?

Comment: There is no algorithm for predicate calculus corresponding to truth table: validity is undecidable. You to find a derivation and use soundness theorem

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And what if I transform the predicate in a preposition and check the truth table of preposition? Is it OK?

Comment: Try to apply it to $\forall x (x=x) \vDash t=t$...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I put $p \equiv \forall x (x =x)$ and $q \equiv t = t$. So I have $p \to q$ and it is not a tautology. This implies that $\forall x (x =x) \not \models t = t$. But it sounds strange to me...

Comment: Perfect: but $p \to q$ is not valid while the predicate logic formula is.

Comment: The issue is that every predicate logic instance of a prop taut is valid but not vice versa.

Comment: If every predicate logic validity could be reduced to a propositional logic one, there would be no need for predicate logic to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove a consequence purely semantically, i.e. without some syntactic calculus like natural deduction or tableaus, you have to provide an informal (mathematical English) argument that under the assumption that the premises hold in some given structure, the consequence must hold there as well. You need to systematically dissect the premises into their subformulas by unpacking their truth conditons, then reassemble them to show that the conclusion can be obtained under these conditions as well.

Example: $\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x) \vDash \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \newcommand{\s}{\mathfrak{A}}$

Assume $\s, v \models \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$ for some structure $\s$ and assignment $v$.
Then $\s, v \models \forall x P(x)$ or $\s, v \models \forall x Q(x)$. Proof by cases:
Case 1: $\s, v \models \forall x P(x)$.
Then $\s, v[x \mapsto a] \models P(x)$ for $a \in D$ arabitrary.
But then also $\s, v[x \mapsto a] \models P(x)$ or $\s, v[x \mapsto a] \models Q(x)$.
Therefore  $\s, v[x \mapsto a] \models P(x) \lor Q(x)$.
Since $a$ was arbitrary, the above holds for all $a \in D$, hence $\s, v \models \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$.
Case 2: $\s, v \models \forall x Q(x)$.
(Analogous).
Since  $\s, v \models \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ follows in any of the cases, it holds whenever $\s, v \models \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$.
Hence $\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x) \vDash \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$.

As you can see, in lines 1-4 the premise is disassembled according to the semantics clauses for the respective main operator (line 2: $\lor$, line 4: $\forall$), and in lines 5-7 it goes the opoosite direction and the established facts are used to build up the conclusion formula from the truth conditions (line 6: $\lor$, line 7: $\forall$). If the consequence claim had more than one premise, you would just add each of them holding as an additional assumption that you can make use of throughout the proof. Under the condition that the model is arbitrary and no further assumptions were made other than the premises holding, the observations can be generalized to all structures, which proves the consequence relation.

Of course there is also the possibility of giving a formal proof, i.e. a deduction in some proof system like natural deduction or the tableau calculus; this is what is shown in the other two answers.

---

To prove that a consequence claim does not hold, you have to provide a counter model, i.e. a structure in which all the premises are true but the conclusion is false, and show that it is one.

Example: $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \not \vDash \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$

Counter model:
$\s = \langle \mathbb{N}, [P \mapsto \{x: x \text{ is even}\}, Q \mapsto \{x: x \text{ is odd}\}] \rangle, v \text{ arbitrary}$
For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, either $n \in \{x: x \text{ is even}\}$ or $n \in \{x: x \text{ is odd}\}$, hence for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\s, v[x \mapsto n] \models P(x)$ or $\s, v[x \mapsto n] \models Q(x)$ and thereby $\s, v[x \mapsto n] \models P(x) \lor Q(x)$, hence $\s, v \models \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$.
$1 \not \in \{x: x \text{ is even}\}$, so $\s, v[x \mapsto 1] \not \models P(x)$, therefore $\s, v \not \models \forall x P(x)$. Analogous for $\forall x Q(x)$ with $[x \mapsto 0]$. Since $\s, v \not \models \forall x P(x)$ and $\s, v \not \models \forall x Q(x)$, it holds that $\s, v \not \models \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$.
Since with $\s, v$ there exists a structure such that $\s, v \models \forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ but $\s, v \not \models \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$, we have that $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \not \vDash \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$.

This one counter model is enough to show that truth is not preserved under every interpretation, and therefore the consequence does not hold.

As for the alternative of a formal proof, natural deduction can not be used to show an invalidity, but it is sometimes (though not always) possible to construct a counter model from the tableau method.

---

To prove a logical equivalence, you have to either argue with two separate proofs that both directions of the consequence relation hold, or come up with a unified proof where every step works in two directions, i.e. a series of $\iff$s showing that the truth conditions for the sides coincide.

To refute an equivalence, you need to provide a counter model for one of the directions. Here, the counter model for $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \not \vDash \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$ also shows that the two can not be equivalent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127294/discussion-on-answer-by-lemontree-how-to-prove-logical-consequence-in-predicate).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, it's still not letting me post in chat. It shows me in the room while telling me I'm offline. I've tried a couple of browsers and switching off addons, but no dice :( Maybe it doesn't like mobile? Could you add this to the chat please => https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193177/is-analytic-semantic-tableaux-a-semantic-method => and I promise this is the last time I spam the comments :)

Comment: @lemontree I replied in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

Let $F(v)$ be a formula whose only free variable is $v.$

In first-order logic, $$\exists x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(a))\;\vDash\;[\forall x P(x)]\rightarrow Q(a)$$ ie equivalent to $$\exists x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(a))\;\vdash\;[\forall x P(x)]\rightarrow Q(a),$$ which can be established using natural-deduction inference rules (on the right of [this webpage](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) and the proof below) in a proof like this:

[image]

(Here, only lines $5$ and $7$ are tautological consequences, i.e., can be derived using truth tables.)

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: What you're asking for is more properly known as *Semantic Consequence.*

Before we get on how to actually do that it's important to point out some relevant features of Classic Predicate Logic.

Firstly, there are 2 basic categories - Monadic, or one place, Predicate Logic (MQL), and Polyadic, or multiple place, Predicate Logic (PQL).

MQL is sound, complete and decidable.

PQL is sound, complete and semi-decidable.

A system of formal logic is Sound if and only if every syntactically provable sequent is semantically valid.

A system of formal logic is Complete if and only if every semantically valid sequent is syntactically provable.

A system of formal logic is Decidable if and only if for each and every sequent of the system there exists a decision procedure for validity and invalidity. For Propositional Logic one procedure is a Truth Table.

So what does semi-decidable mean wrt to PQL? It means that there exists a decision procedure for every valid sequent, but there doesn't exist a decision procedure for every invalid sequent - some invalid sequents can't be shown to be invalid via an algorithm. We can, however, show they're invalid by coming up with what's known as an Invalidating Predicate Logic Interpretation (IQLI) - basically a counterexample.

So what's the method? The method is a Truth Tree, which is commonly known as Analytic/Semantic Tableux.

Some general info can be found here - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux

An algorithm that will actually do it for you can be found here - https://www.umsu.de/trees/

I'd recommend Logic by Paul Tomassi as a really accessible introduction if you want to learn how to use this method. The only downside to the book is he doesn't include any answers to his problems :/ There are plenty of tuts on YouTube and online generally, though, so have a look about and find an author that clicks with you.

Example Truth Tree
[image: Example of the Truth Tree method]

Edit: What the Truth Tree method is effectively doing is looking to see if it's possible for the premises to be true and the conclusion false at the same time. To do this we negate the conclusion and see if it leads to a contradiction. If it does it's valid, if it doesn't and the procedure halts it's invalid. If the procedure doesn't halt then we can't decide if it's invalid. An example where it doesn't halt is $\lnot \forall x[\exists y[Rxy]]$ (an IQLI that demonstrates this sequent is invalid I'll leave to the reader).

Comment: @TenOFour I replied in the chat.

Comment: @rookie_of_math, I'm still locked out of chat :( Lem's answer isn't wrong, our disagreement is about the sem/syn distinction, and what you were looking for. If all you want to do is prove sem validity, then I'd go for Truth Trees b/c it's really easy, like, you'll learn it in 20mins easy. Spotting which invalid sequents won't halt is easy too, so don't worry about it being semi-decidable (UIN before EIN). I'd also recommend getting a textbook to work through as it's much more thorough than searching for things a bit at a time :)

Comment: @TenOFour OK. Thank you. Can you suggest some text? I am not a college student. I study on my own, so I have no professor to ask for books. Thanks again.

Comment: @rookie_of_math I'd suggest Logic by Paul Tomassi. It covers a decent range for an intro, it's proof system is really great for building up understanding, it covers just enough side issues to aid in understanding without overwhelming, and it actually assumes no prior knowledge. He also suggests an awesome book to follow it, Boolos - computability and logic, which uses pretty much the same notation style. Downside? No answers to any questions, but you can always ask here if u get stuck. Hurley an intro to logic is good too. He covers more, but at a much more shallow depth

Comment: @rookie_of_math, here's Tomassi's book in pdf form - https://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/wp-content/uploads/Paul-Tomassi-Logic.pdf though you can often get the paper version for cheap on amazon :)

Comment: OK: thanks for all.